# Java 8 - Update two properties in same Stream code

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm wondering if there is a way I can update two times an object in a `Stream` lambda code, I need to update two properties of a class, I need to update the `value` and the `recordsCount` properties

Object:

```
public class HistoricDataModelParsed {

private Date   startDate;
private Date   endDate;
private Double value;
private int    recordsCount;

}
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
val existingRecord = response.stream()
     .filter(dateTime ->fromDate.equals(dateTime.getStartDate()))
     .findAny()
     .orElse(null);


response.stream()
     .filter(dateTime ->fromDate.equals(dateTime.getStartDate()))
     .findAny()
     .orElse(existingRecord)
     .setValue(valueAdded)
     .setRecordsCount(amount);
```

But I got this error: **"Cannot invoke `setRecordsCount(int)` on the primitive type void"**

So I ended up doing the stream two times to update each of the two fields I needed

```
response.stream()
     .filter(dateTime ->fromDate.equals(dateTime.getStartDate()))
     .findAny()
     .orElse(existingRecord)
     .setValue(valueAdded);
                
 response.stream()
     .filter(dateTime ->fromDate.equals(dateTime.getStartDate()))
     .findAny()
     .orElse(existingRecord)
     .setRecordsCount(amount);
```

Is there a way I can achieve what I need without the need to stream two times the list?

Comment: You shouldn't use `Date`.

Comment: What exactly is existingRecord?

Comment: @MCEmperor can you elaborate why?

Comment: @MohamedAneesA updated the question to add what is that variable

Comment: @xThunder Of course. [Here is something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969651/507738). Furthermore, the new API (in the `java.time` package) is more complete, as it also [models concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969528/507738) not available in the old API, like periods and durations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `setValue` is `void` and **not** `HistoricDataModelParsed`. So you cannot invoke the method `setRecordsCount` which is in `HistoricDataModelParsed` class.

You could have added a method in `HistoricDataModelParsed` which takes two parameters for `value` and `recordsCount`:

```java
public void setValueAndCount(Double value, int count) {
    this.value = value;
    this.recordsCount = count;
}
```

Then call this method after `orElse`:

```java
response.stream()
     .filter(dateTime ->fromDate.equals(dateTime.getStartDate()))
     .findAny()
     .orElse(existingRecord)
     .setValueAndCount(valueAdded, amount);
```

Answer (score 2):

The state of an object should not change within a stream. It can lead to inconsistent results. But you can create new instances of the objects and pass new values via the constructor. Here is a simple record that demonstrates the method. Records are basically immutable classes that have no setters.  The getters are the names of the variables.  A class would also work in this example.

```
record Temp(int getA, int getB) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + getA + ", " + getB  +"]";
    }
}
```

Some data

```
    List<Temp> list = List.of(new Temp(10, 20), new Temp(50, 200),
        new Temp(100, 200));
```

And the transformation.  A new instance of `Temp` with new values is created along with the old ones to completely populate the constructor.  Otherwise, the existing object is passed along.

```
List<Temp> result = list.stream().map(
        t -> t.getA() == 50 ? new Temp(2000, t.getB()) : t)
        .toList();

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
[[10, 20], [2000, 200], [100, 200]]
```

To answer the `void` error you got it's because a stream expects values to continue thru out the stream  so if a method is void, it isn't returning anything so you would have to return it.  Here is an example:

```
stream.map(t->{voidReturnMethod(t); return t;}).toList();
```

The return ensures the pipeline continues.

Answer (score 2):

Simply store the result of `orElse` and then call your methods on it.

```
HistoricDataModelParsed record = 
    response.stream()
        .filter(dateTime -> fromDate.equals(dateTime.getStartDate()))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(existingRecord);

record.setValue(valueAdded)
record.setRecordsCount(amount);
```